# Fastest way to count number of uppercase characters in C#

Tags: c#, linq

What is the efficiency of this? ...

```
CommentText.ToCharArray().Where(c => c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z').Count()
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ok, just knocked up some code to time your method against this:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsUpper(s[i])) count++;
}
```

The result:

> Yours: 19737 ticks
>
> Mine: 118 ticks

Pretty big difference! Sometimes the most straight-forward way is the most efficient.

**Edit**

Just out of interest, this:

```
int count = s.Count(c => char.IsUpper(c));
```

Comes in at at around 2500 ticks. So for a "Linqy" one-liner it's pretty quick.

Comment: D'oh! Pipped at the post, almost exactly the same solution. Well done Matt, damn stupid slow fingers . . .

Comment: By the way, +1 mate, you earned it :)

Comment: Could you try the same test having taken out the unnecessary call to ToCharArray?

Comment: @Binary right batch 'atcha, since I hadn't considered the "foreach" approach.

Comment: @Jon Without the ToCharArray it's around 18000 ticks, so a tad faster.

Comment: @Jon I've updated the post - removing the "Where" was the clincher.

Comment: Make it faster! Remove the index checking by fixing the pointer, then if you define upper case, then you could probably do away with that branch as well. i.e. if upper case -eq c > 0x60, then it's easy, otherwise it's trickier.

Comment: Be warned though, that testing for (c => c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') is not the same as (c => Char.IsUpper(c))

Comment: @John "Remove the index checking by fixing the pointer"? Are you talking C/C++ here?

Comment: A pointer could be used if fixing the object inside an unsafe block. That would make the loop slightly faster, but I think that the overhead of fixing the object makes the overall operation slower.

Comment: @Matt Does s.Count(char.IsUpper) give the same timing as s.Count(c => char.IsUpper(c)) ?

Comment: @porum Yes, performs the same (and the former is easier to read so I'd go with that).

Answer (score 7):

First there is no reason you need to call `ToCharArray()` since, assuming `CommentText` is a string it is already an `IEnumerable<char>`. Second, you should probably be calling `char.IsUpper` instead of assuming you are only dealing with ASCII values. The code should really look like,

```
CommentText.Count(char.IsUpper)
```

Third, if you are worried about speed there isn't much that can beat the old for loop,

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < CommentText.Length; i++) 
   if (char.IsUpper(CommentText[i]) count++;
```

In general, calling any method is going to be slower than inlining the code but this kind of optimization should only be done if you are absolutely sure this is the bottle-neck in your code.

Comment: Dude, should "there is much" be "there isn't much"?

Answer (score 4):

You're only counting standard ASCII and not ÃÐÊ etc.

How about

```
CommentText.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsUpper(c)).Count()
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I was looking for c.Upper in intellisense - didn't think of the other.

Comment: Don't forget: This counts the number of uppercase letters regardless of the number of words.

Answer (score 4):

Without even testing I'd say

```
int count = 0;
foreach (char c in commentText)
{
    if (Char.IsUpper(c))
        count++;
}
```

is faster, off now to test it.

Comment: Yep that's on par (or perhaps even a few ticks faster) than my "for" loop.

Comment: Not bothering to test it, as Matt Hamilton was considerate enough to do this for me :)

Comment: Yes, this is almost half as fast as a `for` loop. Beats me why.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing with that code is to create a collection with the characters, then create a new collection containing only the uppercase characters, then loop through that collection only to find out how many there are.

This will perform better (but still not quite as good as a plain loop), as it doesn't create the intermediate collections:

```
CommentText.Count(c => Char.IsUpper(c))
```

Edit: Removed the ToCharArray call also, as Matt suggested.

Comment: +1 for moving the predicate into the Count. Take away the ToCharArray as well and it speeds up dramatically.

Comment: Good point. I did something similar before and then the ToCharArray was needed, but not in this case. :)

Answer (score 2):

I've got this

```
Regex x = new Regex("[A-Z]{1}", 
  RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
int c = x.Matches(s).Count;
```

<del>but I don't know if its particularly quick. It won't get special chars either, I s'pose</del>

**EDIT:**

Quick comparison to this question's answer. Debug in vshost, 10'000 iterations with the string:
**aBcDeFGHi1287jKK6437628asghwHllmTbynerA**

- The answer: 20-30 ms
- The regex solution: 140-170 ms

Comment: Thanks for the comparison - I wondered how a regex would stack up.

Comment: You can mash this into one line: `Regex.Matches(s, "[A-Z]{1}", 
  RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant).Count;`